# How to trace which enviroment variable is coming from

Tags: centos, environment-variables

My colleague has created an JAVA_HOME variable somewhere but he could not remember.

I have check /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, /root/.bash_profile, /root/.bashrc. All these files does not have a line to set JAVA_HOME, but it still keep coming back with old values.

So, is there a way to find out where is it coming from?

Comment: It might help to say what environment it's always coming back into. At login time into an interactive shell? Into the environment of a daemon that is started by init scripts? root? another user?

Comment: Beautiful, informative answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one crude but effective way:

cd / 
grep -r "JAVA_HOME" .

This will recursively search all subdirectories under the starting point (the UNIX root directory, in this example) for any file containing the string 'JAVA_HOME'.

You can use grep -r --include="*.ext" "JAVA_HOME" . if you want to restrict your searches to files having the extension .ext.

Comment: I just tried and found a few lines at .bash_history and .viminfo. I got to clear the history and .viminfo file to see what happens.

Comment: What happened is a little weird, I couldn't find what was causing the problem. I had to use unset to JAVA_HOME in my bash_rc and set it to a proper path.